# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a function to fetch data through api and now I'm trying to check from the data value of this function, but every time I get the following error:

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<List<AllProductModel>>', is a potentially non-nullable type.
```

my function:

```
Future <List<AllProductModel>> fetchYourProduct(Uid) async {
  final url =
      'https://*****************.php?UserPost=' + Uid.toString();
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  final body = json.decode(response.body);
  if (json.decode(response.body)!="Data not found") { //here problem 
    return body.map<AllProductModel>(AllProductModel.fromJson).toList();
  }else{

  }
}
```

I try to make if statement to see if the data I get from api same string I was add or not.
The function without if statement it's working fine but I need to add if statement.

Data model:

```
class AllProductModel {

  String? name;
 

  AllProductModel(
      {
        this.name,
      
 });

  static AllProductModel  fromJson(json) => AllProductModel(
 
    name : json['name'].toString(),

  );
  }
```

How I can solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a function that has a non-nullable return type (return can't be null), you need to return that type in **every possible case inside that function** (or throw an exception).

For example, your function returns a `Future<List<AllProductModel>>`. This is not nullable, hence, for every single case of your function, you must either:

1. Return that specified type; or
2. Do a throw statement, like this: `throw <some_exception>`

You return something inside the `if` clause of your statement, however, you don't return anything inside the `else` clause. That's your problem.

Solution: Either return something inside that `else` clause, or throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

**You can also try and check if this works..**

You can make the `fetchYourProduct()` function nullable by changing the return type from **Future <List>** to **Future <List>?**.

Answer (score 1):

Future <List> fetchYourProduct(Uid) async {
final url =
'https://*****************.php?UserPost=' + Uid.toString();
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
final body = json.decode(response.body);
if (json.decode(response.body)!="Data not found") { //here problem
return body.map(AllProductModel.fromJson).toList();
}else{
return [];
}
}

you should to return If and else both of statement compulsory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).